# How can we show this simple inequality?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $m>1$, $\gamma\ge\frac1m$, $C_3>0$, $\lambda>0$, $t_0\ge0$ and $$f(t):=\left(C_3^{1-m}+m(m-1)\gamma\lambda(t-t_0)\right)^{-\frac1{m-1}}\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge t_0.$$ Assume $g:[t_0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $$g(t)\ge c_1^\gamma d^\gamma f(t)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge t_0.\tag1$$ for some $c_1,d>0$.

> Why can we conclude that there is a $c>0$ such that $$g(t)\ge cd^\gamma(t+1)^{-\frac1{m-1}}\tag2$$ for all $\ge t_0$?

I'm really struggling to see $(2)$. Is there an elementary inequality which yields $(2)$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $m>1,\gamma\geq \frac 1 m>0,C_3>0,\lambda>0,t_0\geq 0,c_1,d>0$ are constant. Then $c>0$ can be determined by comparison. For simplicity, let $c=c_1^\gamma\cdot c'.$  Then to achieve (2), it suffices to have by (1) that  $$c_1^\gamma d^\gamma f(t)\geq cd^\gamma (t+1)^{-\frac 1{m-1}}=c_1^\gamma c'd^\gamma (t+1)^{-\frac 1{m-1}},~{\rm for~}t\geq t_0$$

$$\Leftrightarrow f(t)\geq c'(t+1)^{-\frac 1{m-1}},~{\rm for~}t\geq t_0.$$ Using the definition of $f(t)$, the latter is equivalent to $$\left[\frac{t+1}{C_3^{1-m}+m(m-1)\gamma \lambda(t-t_0)}\right]^{\frac 1 {m-1}}\geq c',~{\rm for~}t\geq t_0.$$ For convenience, let $$h(t)=\frac{t+1}{C_3^{1-m}+m(m-1)\gamma \lambda(t-t_0)}.$$ This is a fractional linear transformation in $t$. One sees that $h(t)>0$ for $t\geq t_0$, and the greatest lower bound for $(h(t))^{1/(m-1)}$ for $t\geq t_0$ can be determined. To solve for the greatest lower bound, compute
$$h'(t)=\frac{C_3^{1-m}-m(m-1)\gamma \lambda t_0-m(m-1)\gamma\lambda}{(C_3^{1-m}+m(m-1)\gamma \lambda(t-t_0))^2}.$$ One can divide into two cases.

**Case 1**. If $h'(t)\geq 0$, i.e. $C_3^{1-m}\geq m(m-1)\gamma\lambda(t_0+1),$ then one has the greatest lower bound $$h(t_0)^{\frac 1{m-1}}=\left[\frac{t_0+1}{C_3^{1-m}}\right]^{\frac 1{m-1}}=C_3(t_0+1)^{\frac 1 {m-1}}.$$

**Case 2**. If $h'(t)< 0$, i.e. $C_3^{1-m}< m(m-1)\gamma\lambda(t_0+1),$ then one has the greatest lower bound $$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}h(t)^{\frac 1{m-1}}=\left[\frac 1{m(m-1)\gamma\lambda}\right]^{\frac 1 {m-1}}.$$

These greatest lower bounds can serve as $c'$, and the required constant $c$ can be explicitly determined, based on the above two cases, as $c=c_1^{\gamma}\cdot c'.$ To cover both cases, one can take $$c=c_1^{\gamma}\cdot \min\left(C_3(t_0+1)^{\frac 1 {m-1}},\left[\frac 1{m(m-1)\gamma\lambda}\right]^{\frac 1 {m-1}}\right).$$ QED